# Как поместить дочерний класс в контейнер map с указателем на базовый класс?

Tags: c++, наследование, map, virtual, undefined-reference

Проблема в следующем. Есть родительский класс и дочерний класс.

```cpp
class Parent {
public:
    virtual ~Parent();
    virtual void execute() = 0;
protected:
    Parent(DataStruct *data) : data(data) {}
    DataStruct *data;
};

class Derived1 : public Parent {
public:
    Derived1(DataStruct *data, string str) : Parent(data), str(str) {}
    void execute();
private:
    string str;
};
```

Есть контейнер map с типами string и Parent*. Я пытаюсь положить в него указатель на дочерний класс.

```cpp
map <string, Parent*> myMap;
myMap["derived-1"] = new Derived1(myData, myString);
```

При компиляции выдается ошибка:

```
in function `Derived1::Derived1(DataStruct*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
undefined reference to `Parent::~Parent()'
undefined reference to `vtable for Derived1'
undefined reference to `vtable for Parent'
```

Но этой ошибки нет в списке проблем. Почему это происходит, что это значит, как это исправить?

Comment: Где он дочерний? Нужно ведь наследоваться: `class Derived1 : public Parent {` К тому же у класса `Parent` должен быть деструктор с телом, а не только прототип.

Comment: Упс, пропустил. Сейчас исправлю!

Comment: @edKotinsky что-то вы забыли, потому что ваш пример прекрасно компилируется: https://godbolt.org/z/c7ov31rMs

Comment: @edKotinsky также хочу заметить, что в Derived1 конструкторе у вас происходит перекрытие имен - аргумент и переменная-член имеют одинаковое название str, это также может привести к проблемам. В конструкторе Parent тоже перекрытие имени data

Comment: @ComeInRage да, может приводить к проблемам, но у меня такого еще не было. У меня не компилировался. Я решил эту проблему - она заключалась в том, что методы execute у дочерних классов и деструктор класса-родителя должны иметь тело. Иначе компилятор ругается весьма витиевато: D:/msys/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\PCP.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZTV21CommandChangeTemplate[.refptr._ZTV21CommandChangeTemplate]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for CommandChangeTemplate'

Comment: @edKotinsky Учитывая текст ошибки компиляции, я почти уверен, что вы не дописали пример и где-то в реализации методов вы зовете виртуальную функцию в конструкторе или деструкторе. Это прямой путь к ошибкам : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750855/undefined-reference-to-method-in-parent-class

Comment: @edKotinsky а вы объявили виртуальный метод, но не добавили ему определение?) Советую читать варнинги компилятора или IntelliSense, если у вас VS

Comment: @ComeInRage у меня VS Code. Варнингов не было, в том-то и дело...

Comment: @edKotinsky проверьте включен ли у вас IntelliSense. И включены ли варнинги компилятора. Они оба должны ругаться в случае, если у вас есть объявление функции/метода, но нет определения

Comment: @ComeInRage да, посмотрел, как включаются варнинги. set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -Wall) Важная вещь, теперь буду везде прописывать. Спасибо!)

Comment: @edKotinsky вам было бы проще использовать VS обычную, если вы на Windows. У студии куда больше инструментов и возможностей, да и удобство выше, чем VS Code. Code - это редактор, как продвинутый блокнот. Для разработки его стоит использовать, когда у вас по какой-то причине нельзя использовать VS. Например если вы на Linux без интерфейса (яркий пример - это необходимость собрать проект на Linux, а вы на Windows, тогда вы используете WSL + VS Code + опционально какие-нибудь Докеры)

Comment: @ComeInRage после падения системы VS не устанавливается. Переустанавливать не хочу, копаться - тоже. Руки не доходили. Поставил VS Code просто попробовать, так и остался - интересно же, как это работает на низком уровне. Изучение по хардкору.